# Adding String array into setListAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to add a Class array into my Listview.

on debug it stucks on setListAdapter line without any special error.

when I compile it passes my splash screen and open's menu.java but nothing happens when I click items on my list.

here is my Menu.java

```java
package com.android;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = { "MainActivity", "Acl", "Bcl", "Ccl",
            "Dcl", "Ecl", "Fcl" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String classpos = classes[position];
        try {

            Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.android.MainActivity"  classpos);
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);

            startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and here my code related part of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: have you define listview in activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in creating the class name in you code.

Try this,

String classpos = "com.android."+classes[position];

Class ourClass = Class.forName(classpos);